# Microsoft graph notification when new channel created in teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I would like to receive a webhook notification when a new channel is created in a group in microsoft teams.

I already implemented receiving notifications when user is added to a group through teams (using this API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0). Unfortunately, it seems like group subscription is not triggered when a new channel is added.

Is there any other subscription I can use? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the possibility to add a bot to the Team, then bots can receive this using the bot event mechanisms. Have a look at [Handle bot events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications), and in particular [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#channel-updates). Once your bot has received the notification, you can of course do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks promising. Will try to implement this.

Comment: Glad to help, post questions here if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to channel events is not supported today by Microsoft graph. You can upvote the following idea to help prioritize efforts and also be notified whenever progress is made.

https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37288522-microsoft-teams-create-channel-with-a-webhook

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you sure the suggestion you linked is the same problem though? I don't need a webhook when a message is posted to a channel, but only when the channel itself is created.

Comment: Yes this idea could be interpreted two different ways. Feel free to create another idea and link it here.